# Inequality demonstration, how can I understand how to prove those.

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, solution-verification

So, i got some problems with inequalities demonstrations.

The fact is that i don't understand where you should start off to get to the conclusion.

I had some excercises which I solved using the following formula: $$(a^2+b^2)\ge2ab$$

But now I'm stuck with this inequality:

Having:
$$a,b,c\gt0$$

Prove:
$$\frac{2}{a+b}+\frac{2}{b+c}+\frac{2}{c+a}\ge\frac{9}{a+b+c}$$

I tried to use the cube of a binomial and the square of a trinomial but I didn't get so far.

I'm not asking necessarily for the solution, i'm more concerned about how to think, so maybe a little explanation with some hints would be even more appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590720/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262371/42969

Comment: Build up your tools for recognizing when various approaches could be used. For example, if we set $ a+b+ c = K$ fixed, then we have $ \sum \frac{2}{K-a} \geq \frac{9}{K}$. This is "variable-seperable" so Jensens or the tangent line approach should work.

Comment: this is just AM$\ge$HM